# QtCreator debugger stuck "running"

Tags: c++, qt, debugging

I'm trying to debug my Qt QML application, but the debugger seems to get stuck in the "running" phase when I step into these lines of code:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///main.qml")));
```

I can't step over or do anything except stop the debugger. Any ideas as to what's going on?

Comment: Have you tried hitting the pause button and checking the stack trace?

Comment: yes, but I'm not sure what I should see. It's at Level 6 in the main function.

Comment: Have you found an answer? I am facing exactly the same problem now.